# Prevent unhiding worksheet from VBA on another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel workbook report which is view by 5 persons. This report has 10 sheets, 9 of which are hidden using `Sheets("Sheet2-10").Visible = xlVeryHidden` .

However, my worksheet is not secure because people can unhide worksheets 2 to 10 by using `Sheets("Sheet2-10").Visible = true` (e.g. called from another workbook).

How do I protect my worksheet against someone trying to do this?

Comment: have you tried protecting the workbook?

Comment: Which this way. I can not call visible methods from Private Sub Workbook_Open() . I have some VBA script in this sub.

Comment: +1 Good question. I only recently discovered `xlVeryHidden` but it seems what ever passwords I put on the workbook it is pretty easy to make the sheet visible again. Maybe an approach other than `.Visible` is required.

Comment: possible worth posting on here as well [**http://superuser.com/**](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't completely solve your issue, but as an FYI, Excel allows you to name sheets beginning with a quotation mark followed by an apostrophe and then letters or anything else.  So you could have a sheet named "'Sheet1.  If you try `Worksheets(""'Sheet1").Visible`, you get a compiler error.  Users could still call it by index number however.

Comment: That sheet can still be referenced, using `Worksheets("""'Sheet1").Visible`

Comment: or a simple `for each Sh in thisworkbook.worksheets`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easy man. you just need to protect your VBA code with a password:

[image: Protecting VBA code]

With this protection noone can see *Microsoft Excel Object*. So now, you just need to change your veryHidden sheet name to an awful name - hash name. like `Sheets("FFJAR31GMCJ4ASAL8PYXXFE")`

To make you like easier to code, you can set sheet's name in a constant.

Example:

```
Const MY_HIDDEN_SHEET As String = "FFJAR31GMCJ4ASAL8PYXXFE"

Sub f()
    MsgBox "My hidden sheet name is " & MY_HIDDEN_SHEET
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just protect your workbook structure:

[image]